# How much memory is used by Mondrian?

Tags: memory, olap, mondrian

How much memory is used by Mondrian? Can I allocate more memory for the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?64762-Allocate-more-memory-to-mondrian) forum answer Mondrian uses the memory available to JVM. So to increase, the JVM's memory must be increased.